# Listen to a url in nodeJs

Tags: node.js

I have an url like:

```
http://some-url:3978/api/stream
```

How Can I listen to it in node to see all incoming messages ?

Or the equivalent of

```
curl http://localhost:3978/api/stream
```

Comment: what is the meanign of listen over here? do you want read data form that URL?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Yes. I want to read data from that url

Comment: posted a solution which tells on reading data from api/url either from backend or frontend, does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your data on backend Use a package called as [postman-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postman-request). simplest way to make HTTP calls (GET,POST), supports promise too, another alternative is to use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) which works in browser as well as with express too.

If you want this from client side, you can use browser based API like **fetch,axios,xmlhttpprequests**

```
npm i postman-request //for installation

//example
const request = require('postman-request');

    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
      console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working. There is no log showing up, but if I log something before this request function, it shows. So The place where it's written is correct

Comment: Update. It works great, my bad. Thank you for your help :)